# How to increase maximum message size quota for incoming messages for a WCF service when (65536) has been exceeded

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, service

Issue : The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element

CONFIG File Details.

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceBehavior"
           name="GenServiceLibrary.IFileUploadService">
    <endpoint address="FileUploadService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="CoreServiceBehavior"
              bindingConfiguration="WCFServiceBinding" 
              contract="GenServiceLibrary.IFileUploadService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceBehavior"
           name="GenServiceLibrary.Service.svc">
    <endpoint address="Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="CoreServiceBehavior"
              bindingConfiguration="WCFServiceBinding"
              contract="GenServiceLibrary.ICommonService"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WCFServiceBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="1024000"
             maxBufferSize="1024000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="1024000" maxStringContentLength="1024000"
                    maxArrayLength="1024000" maxBytesPerRead="1024000"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="1024000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WCFServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CoreServiceBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hard to decipher what your issue really is from what little you’ve posted.

In order to transfer large messages with WCF, you need to make sure that the message quota values are increased in BOTH the client and server configuration files in order to address the issue.  Otherwise, the resolution is relatively simple, just adjust the configuration to have higher values.

For example:

```
<binding name="DefaultBasicHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="1024000" maxBufferSize="1024000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="1024000" maxStringContentLength="1024000" maxArrayLength="1024000" maxBytesPerRead="1024000" maxNameTableCharCount="1024000" />
</binding>
```

Comment: Are the values increased in BOTH the client and server configurations?

Comment: Thanks Seymour.yes,but it is happening when iam using the service inside the server only.